# Machine Learning Techniques in Spam Filtering by Konstantin Tretyakov

Tags: machine-learning, spam-prevention

http://ats.cs.ut.ee/u/kt/hw/spam/spam.pdf

First of all, I am not sure if this is even a good question for stack overflow as it's not directly related to code, I just couldn't think of a different place to ask it.

I have been looking into machine learning for a report I have to make, and wanted to write something about spam filtering. The link above looks like a pretty good and trustworthy source, but I am probably pretty dumb and just don't understand what they are saying in the neural networks part (page 68 and on). In the part where they adjust w en b, they use c and x to adjust it. C is 1 or -1, for as far as I understand it (might be wrong here too though :(), but x is the prepared -words like 'the' removed, words like 'running' stemmed to 'run'- mail itself, right? How can you use that to rework the weight w? they say w-new = w-old + cx, but how do you multiply a non-integer?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Yes, this question is off topic on SO. It's quite broad and we don't get what you are actually asking about. Please read about how to ask question on SO [here](stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what's on topic on the site [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The input of a neural network, as they said, is a `feature vector`, so a vector representation of the words you want to analyze. You have to encode or represent your words in a way that can be used by the neural network as input feature vector.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Vector Representation of word. In existing ml libraries there are tools to build such representations automatically (like [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) or [that](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer))

In general the idea is trivial. Imagine that you know there are 1000 of words out there in your document corpus. No more no less. Simplest way of vector representation for words is to just build a sparse matrix of size 1000x1 where you for each specific word you will have all rows as 0 and one of rows marked with 1 (what is often called 'one-hot-encoding')

This is an ugly representation though, usually something more effective is used, like TF-IDF representation - though it is a variation of same idea.